# Angularjs $scope.object from nested object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a $scope.currentUser object and a nested OwnedCompany object like so:

```
app.controller 'dashboardsCtrl', ($scope, Api, Auth) ->
  $scope.currentUser = Api.User.get(id: Auth.user())
  $scope.ownedCompany = $scope.currentUser.owned_company
```

`{{currentUser}}` returns:

```
user: { 
  "name": "Ryan",
  "owned_company":{"name":"XYZ"}
}
```

`{{currentUser.owned_company}}` returns:

```
{"name":"XYZ"}
```

but `{{ownedCompany}}` returns nil.

---

How do I get `$scope.ownedCompany = $scope.currentUser.owned_company` to work?

---

**Solution**

As per @mohamedrias' answer,

```
app.controller 'dashboardsCtrl', ($scope, Api, Auth) ->
  Api.User.get(id: Auth.user()).$promise.then (currentUser) ->
    $scope.currentUser = currentUser
    $scope.ownedCompany = currentUser.owned_company
```

`{{ownedCompany}}` returns:

```
{name:"XYZ"}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jpno6ft2/1/

Comment: Are you sure that there's no mistake while writing the variable name ?? or in the character casing ??

Comment: if `currentUser.owned_company` is changed at run time then use a watch or set the value after the change is happened - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jpno6ft2/2/

Comment: `$scope.currentUser.owned_company` returns an object with property name so try `{{ownedCompany.name}}` to get `XYZ`

Comment: Using $watch - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jpno6ft2/3/ or without - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jpno6ft2/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $scope.currentUser = Api.User.get(id: Auth.user())
```

It's an async call from where you're getting the current user details. So it will resole later.

Either you must use promise ad put

```
  $scope.ownedCompany = $scope.currentUser.owned_company
```

Inside the `then` block.

Else register a `watch` on that object and perform the assignment.

Comment: This works great. I'll add the solution to my question. Thanks Mohamed.